# How can I use Python to get a download link with a password for onedrive

Tags: python, python-3.x, onedrive

OneDrive is a great tool, but the downside is that for links shared by others there is no way to download them without a graphical interface.

I've recently been working on how to download OneDrive files that people have shared with me from the command line, and I've now worked out how to bulk push download links to Aria2, a download tool, when the shared links don't have passwords.

```py
header = {
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'dnt': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.51',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'service-worker-navigation-preload': 'true',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'iframe',
    'accept-language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6',
}

def downloadFiles(originalPath, aria2URL, token):
    req = requests.session()
    req = req.get(originalPath, headers=header)

    p = re.search(
        'g_listData = {"wpq":"","Templates":{},"ListData":{ "Row" : ([\s\S]*?),"FirstRow"', req.text)
    jsonData = json.loads(p.group(1))
    redURL = req.url
    redsURL = redURL.split("/")
    downloadURL = "/".join(redsURL[:-1])+"/download.aspx?UniqueId="

    # print(downloadURL)

    s2 = parse.urlparse(redURL)
    header["referer"] = redURL
    header["cookie"] = req.headers["Set-Cookie"]
    header["authority"] = s2.netloc

    # .replace("-", "%2D")

    # print(dd, [cc])
    headerStr = ""
    for key, value in header.items():
        # print(key+':'+str(value))
        headerStr += key+':'+str(value)+"\n"

    # print(headerStr)
    for i in jsonData:
        cc = downloadURL+(i["UniqueId"][1:-1].lower())
        dd = dict(out=i["FileLeafRef"],  header=headerStr)
        jsonreq = json.dumps({'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': 'qwer',
                              'method': 'aria2.addUri',
                              "params": ["token:"+token, [cc], dd]})
        c = requests.post(aria2URL, data=jsonreq)
        pprint(json.loads(c.text))
```

However, if the link itself has a password, although it is possible to post a link that verifies the password, it gets stuck in endless redirects, so how do I solve this problem?

The process of post a link to verify a password:

```py
def getFilesHavePwd(originalPath, password):
    req = requests.session()
    req.cookies.update(header)
    r = req.get(originalPath)
    p = re.search(
        'SideBySideToken" value="(.*?)" />', r.text)
    SideBySideToken = p.group(1)
    p = re.search(
        'id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*?)" />', r.text)
    __VIEWSTATE = p.group(1)
    p = re.search(
        'id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="(.*?)" />', r.text)
    __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR = p.group(1)
    p = re.search(
        '__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.*?)" />', r.text)
    __EVENTVALIDATION = p.group(1)
    s2 = parse.urlparse(originalPath)
    redURL = originalPath
    redsURL = redURL.split("/")
    shareQuery = s2.path.split("/")[-1]
    redsURL[-1] = "guestaccess.aspx?"+s2.query+"&share="+shareQuery
    pwdURL = "/".join(redsURL)
    print(r.headers)
    hewHeader = {
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'dnt': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.51',
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        "connection": "keep-alive",
        'accept-language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6',
        "host": s2.netloc,
        "origin": s2.scheme+"://"+s2.netloc,
        "Referer": originalPath,
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
        'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',

    }

    req.cookies.update(header)
    r = req.post(pwdURL, data={
        "__EVENTTARGET": "btnSubmitPassword",
        "__EVENTARGUMENT": None,
        "SideBySideToken": SideBySideToken,
        "__VIEWSTATE": __VIEWSTATE,
        "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR,
        "__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED": None,
        "__EVENTVALIDATION": __EVENTVALIDATION,
        "txtPassword": password
    }, headers=hewHeader)
    print(r.headers, r.text)
```

A link for test:

https://acgmi-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/support_acgmi_club/Elkm2koDXKFEq1onWqnefdwBTqR7wgm0MiNvmWWrurKskQ?e=qotSdz

Password:`123456`

Comment: There is official [OneDrive API](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/?view=odsp-graph-online) to work without GUI. Microsoft created even [OneDrive SDK for Python](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python)

Comment: but, as in all API, it needs to register your app on special page to get `Client ID` and `Client Secret` to get access to all functions.

Comment: @furas This method can only make their own onedrive files can get direct download links, but for other people who do not have any programming experience, only through the web side of the sharing function to share, there is no way to use the API.

Comment: I don't know if API gives you access to other files but with API should work faster. If someone do not have any programming experience then he has no change to write it your way too :) But if someone create program using any method (yours or with API) then everyone can use it. API usually has this an advantage that is official and Microsoft will not block it - if you try to access it like in browser then it may block it (ie it may send ReCaptcha). But it has disadvantage: modern APIs so complex and registration needs more work - and it can be pain.